# edgeR: Design Matrix not full rank

Tags: r

I am analyzing RNA seq data with four time points and two treatments. Samples were measured at multiple time points and got always the same treatment. I want to make a paired model. The following code always gives me an error stating, that the Design matrix is not of full rank. Why is this design matrix not of full rank?

```
|--------|-----------|------------|
| sample | treatment | time_point |
|--------|-----------|------------|
|   1    |    a      |      1     |
|   1    |    a      |      2     |
|   1    |    a      |      3     |
|   1    |    a      |      4     |
|   2    |    b      |      1     |
|   2    |    b      |      2     |
|   2    |    b      |      3     |
|   2    |    b      |      4     |
|  ...   |   ...     |     ...    |
|--------|-----------|------------|
```

```
merged_vars <- factor(paste(treatment, time_point, sep="."))
design <- stats::model.matrix(~sample+merged_vars)
y <- edgeR::estimateDisp(y, design = design)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes about when one of your predictors can be expressed as a linear combination of the other.

In your example, b.1 + b.2 + b.3 + b.4 gives you the effect of sample 2 , if you look at the model.matrix:

```
df = data.frame(sample=rep(1:2,each=4),
treatment=rep(letters[1:2],each=4),time_point=rep(1:4,2))
df$merged_vars= with(df,factor(paste(treatment, time_point, sep=".")))

model.matrix(~sample +merged_vars,data=df)

  (Intercept) sample merged_varsa.2 merged_varsa.3 merged_varsa.4
1           1      1              0              0              0
2           1      1              1              0              0
3           1      1              0              1              0
4           1      1              0              0              1
5           1      2              0              0              0
6           1      2              0              0              0
7           1      2              0              0              0
8           1      2              0              0              0
  merged_varsb.1 merged_varsb.2 merged_varsb.3 merged_varsb.4
1              0              0              0              0
2              0              0              0              0
3              0              0              0              0
4              0              0              0              0
5              1              0              0              0
6              0              1              0              0
7              0              0              1              0
8              0              0              0              1
```

Also if you do `merged_vars <- factor(paste(treatment, time_point, sep="."))`, you have 1 observation per level, this means no replicates, you cannot do egdeR with it.

I would suggest doing, because it looks like sample and treatment are confounded:

```
design <- stats::model.matrix(~treatment*time_point)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe, I made a bad annotation. I have subject from which I take samples at multiple time points and I would like to see the changes in a subject due to the treatment.

Comment: whatever the case, you have to check that you don't have linear combinations. @Mol1narius, Does it answer your question? -> "Why is this design matrix not of full rank?:

Comment: its a basic linear model problem and as biologist we grind out head what it is